# Ansible User module removes sudo configuration. Why?

Tags: rhel, amazon-ec2, aws, ansible, amazon-linux

An Amazon Linux 2 machine is configured with a user that can sudo without password as follows:

```
# Add user
sudo groupadd -g 2002 one-username
sudo useradd -u 2002 -g 2002 -c "One Username Account" -s /bin/bash -m -d /home/one-username one-username

# Configure SSH for the user
mkdir -p /home/one-username/.ssh
cp -pr /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/one-username/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R one-username:one-username /home/one-username/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/one-username/.ssh
cat << 'EOF' > /etc/sudoers.d/one-username
User_Alias ONE_USERNAME = %one-username
ONE_USERNAME ALL=(ALL)      NOPASSWD: ALL
EOF
chmod 400 /etc/sudoers.d/one-username
# disable login for one-username except through ssh keys
cat << 'EOF' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Match User one-username
        PasswordAuthentication no
        AuthenticationMethods publickey

EOF
# restart sshd
systemctl restart sshd
```

This config is preserved when an ansible playbook adds the same user to a group as follows:

```
 - name: Add user to different-groupname group
   command: usermod -a -G different-groupname one-username
```

However, when the preceding two lines are changed in the playbook to become the following 4 lines, the same user is no longer able to sudo without being prompted for a non-existent password:

```
 - name: Add user to different-groupname group
   user:
     name: one-username
     group: different-groupname
```

> **Why is this happening?  How can Ansible's user module be re-configured here to avoid causing this problem?**

Note:  `different-groupname` group is created separately (and the `one-username` is added to the `different-groupname` separately) in the same way in both situations, and this thus not the cause of the problem here.

Comment: Unrelated: you can `install -m 0400 /dev/stdin /etc/sudoers.d/one-username <<EOF` instead of creating the file and then changing its attributes, saves repeating the filename.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

Command `usermod -a ...` adds the group, but the parameter `group` of the [user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html#user-manage-user-accounts) module "sets the user's primary group".

**Details**

User *one-username* is created with the primary group *one-username*

```
sudo groupadd -g 2002 one-username
sudo useradd -u 2002 -g 2002 ... one-username
```

Members of the group *one-username* are allowed to sudo

```
User_Alias ONE_USERNAME = %one-username
ONE_USERNAME ALL=(ALL)      NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Ansible module [user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html#user-manage-user-accounts) sets the primary group of the user *one-username* to *different-groupname*.

```
user:
  name: one-username
  group: different-groupname
```

Very probably members of the group *different-groupname* are not allowed to sudo.

**Solution**

Use `groups` instead of `group` parameter of the module *user*. Instead of

```
user:
  name: one-username
  group: different-groupname
```

use

```
user:
  name: one-username
  groups:
    - different-groupname
```

(not tested)

Additionally, the `append` keyword of the user module affects the set of groups for a user.  If you add `append: yes`, the `different-groupname` is added to the list of groups for the user:

```
user:
  name: one-username
  append: yes
  groups:
    - different-groupname
```

By default, `append` defaults to `no`, and the user groups are set to the set of groups declared by the `groups` keyword.  If the user belongs to other groups that are not in the `groups` list, the user is removed from those groups.